# npm install errors in jenkins job

Tags: angularjs, jenkins, npm

I am trying to run npm install command and getting the below error; The same package.JSON works fine in local, but when I try to run the command through jenkins job getting the error.

> npm WARN @angular/animations@4.1.2 requires a peer of
>   @angular/core@4.1.2 but none was installed. npm WARN
>   @angular/core@2.3.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4 but none was
>   installed. npm WARN @angular/http@2.3.1 requires a peer of
>   rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed. npm WARN
>   @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.5 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.0
>   but none was installed. npm WARN @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.5
>   requires a peer of @angular/common@^4.0.0 but none was installed. npm
>   WARN @angular/router@3.3.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4 but none
>   was installed. npm WARN @swimlane/ngx-datatable@7.1.1 requires a peer
>   of @angular/common@^4.0.0 but none was installed.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message says that you want to use  `@angular/animations@4.1.2` without `@angular/core@4.1.2`. This usually happens when you are missing or using different versions of modules.

Solution is, try to update your `package.json` dependencies and install missing once.

Comment: Thank you for the solution.